# How to show a customer's address from a customer query

Tags: c#, asp.net, intuit-partner-platform

Is it possible to show the address for customers using a customer query?
I have a customer information page in my cloud application and I cannot seem to access the address, phone, and email properties of the customer.
I would like to be able to show all the information about all customers in the database; ie. company name, customer name, address(billing and shipping), phone numbers(billing, home, fax), and email(billing or home) inside the datagrid.
I used examples from the .NET DevKit 2.0 sample application to build this datagrid.

I have a datagrid bound to my customer query object.

```
<asp:GridView AutoGenerateColumns="False" ID="grdCustInfo"  runat="server" CssClass="custInfo">
   <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Customer Name">
         <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblC1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Company Name">
         <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblC2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DBAName") %>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Bill Address 1">
            <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label ID="lblC3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Address[0].Line1") %>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>    
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The Name and DBName produce the desired information but the Address line doesn't. When run as shown, the app won't load, it just gives me an application error. When I take off the [0] from the address the application starts but I get an error when I access the customer datagrid: 
DataBinding: 'Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.PhysicalAddress[]' does not contain a property with the name 'Line1' 
How do I access the address, email, and phone fields from the customer query or do I need to access the information from a different location or query?

Comment: That's the correct query, you just need to figure out how to get the data into the DataGrid.

Comment: You should add another data grid for the addresses inside a templatefield, bind the addresses collection to it and then template out the address data that you want.

Comment: All I can get it to show is for the address is: 'Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.PhysicalAddress[]' I cannot get it to show anything but this or an error.

Comment: What's your Customer and Address classes look like? and show the relationship between them. Do the Customer class has a property called Address that relates to the instance of the address class?

Comment: When I inspect the customer query object in Visual Studio it has all the data I require as shown in the Intuit Partner Platform (https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0050_Data_Services/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0600_Object_Reference/Customer) The address is in the customer object.

Comment: Expose properties from your Customer class that represents each of your Address properties but gets the data from underlying Address object.

Comment: Can you provide an example of this?

Comment: I have tried all of the properties of PhysicalAddress and I am not getting anywhere. It doesn't seem to allow me to access any of the data within the Physical Address. The line: <%# Bind("Address[0].Line1") %> is the line of code that is giving me trouble. There are 2 addresses tied to each customer (billing and shipping). The only way I can get it to produce anything is when I change the line to: <%# Bind("Address") %> and this will give me Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.PhysicalAddress(). How am I supposed to "Expose properties" if it only gives me the address type?

Comment: As @CraigW mentioned above, add another data grid and bind the Address array to that.